# Why i cant include a .yml in CI/CD, using rules with mine variables?

Tags: gitlab, cicd, yaml

Why my pipeline doesn't work? I just want include this .yml if "NATIVE_COMPILE" is "true".

```yml
variables:
  NATIVE_COMPILE : "true"
include:
  - project: 'pipelines/cicd'
    ref: improve/simplificando-pipes
    file: 'libraries/bundle/java/maven/.gitlab-ci-native.template.yml'
    rules:
      - if: $NATIVE_COMPILE == "true"
```

If i use something like:

```yml
include:
  - project: 'pipelines/cicd'
    ref: improve/simplificando-pipes
    file: 'libraries/bundle/java/maven/.gitlab-ci-native.template.yml'
    rules:
      - if $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /.*--native-compile*/
```

And write "--native-compile" on commit, its works perfectly, but with my variables doesnt work.

Someone can help me, pls ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the variable as a global project variable so that you can get its value in the linked yml file.

Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables